# FFMPEG unable to loop overlay input image for dynamic image overlay

Tags: php, laravel-5, ffmpeg

I am trying to loop an image in images/logo.png(for ex).

I am using php laravel to create dynamic images and overwriting it into images/logo.png.

My ffmpeg code

`ffmpeg -y -listen 1 -i rtmp://192.168.33.11:1935/live/mp4test  -loop 1  -f image2 -i image/logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1024:-1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[stream];[1:v]scale=120:-1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[logo] ; [stream][logo]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10,format=yuv420p[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a:0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -start_number 1 stream.m3u8`

This code works fine if I generate dynamic image using

`until test ; do convert -size 200x100 xc:White -gravity Center  -weight 700 -pointsize 12  -annotate 0 "date" /usr/local/nginx/html/stream/test_stream/datex.png ; mv /usr/local/nginx/html/stream/test_stream/datex.png /usr/local/nginx/html/stream/test_stream/image/logo.png   ; sleep 1 ; done`

This script just generates a image with current time stamp and moves it into images/ as logo.png . And this works absolutely fine.

But when I using my laravel application generate a file move it into images/ ffmpeg starts dropping all the frames.

Please suggest me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. The problem was with the resolution of the images. When I try overlay images of same resolution. I seems to work properly.